# Firestore query documents startsWith a specific character

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to query a firestore collection to get all document that starts with a specific character? For example if I have a collection "Items" that contains:

[image]

I want for example only the document starting with I
I don't know how modify the query , the method charAt[0] is not recognized:

```
return itemRef
      .doc(this.itemsId)
      .collection("october")
      .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId().charAt[0], "==", randomChar)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the top of my head, if interested in the letter "I":

```
var lower = 'I';
var upper = String.fromCharCode(lower.codeUnitAt(0) + 1);

itemRef
      .doc(this.itemsId)
      .collection("october")
      .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId() ">=", lower)
      .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId() "<", upper)
```

Not sure, what happens in case of the letter Z.

Comment: Hi Dabbel, I is an example, it can be any letter the randomChar parameter

Comment: @sirss Check updated answer.